# Convert object to a C# class

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to cast an object to a model class but it's throwing me an error at the 2nd line.

Code:

```
StoreToStoreRequestModel x = (StoreToStoreRequestModel)temp;
StoreToStoreRequestDetailsModel y = x.details;
```

Model:

```
public class StoreToStoreRequestModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string documentNo { get; set; }
    public List<StoreToStoreRequestDetailsModel> details { get; set; }
}
```

I need to access the properties of the StoreToStoreRequestDetailsModel through the StoreToStoreRequestModel since it is a subclass.

The error message is:

> `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<StoreToStoreRequestDetailsModel>' to 'StoreToStoreRequestDetailsModel'`

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: When you have an error, please ensure that you put the error message in your question. In this instance it was quite obvious what the problem was, but the error message helps a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `details` is a `List<T>` which is not the same as a single instance of `StoreToStoreRequestDetailsModel`.

So you should do this instead:

```
List<StoreToStoreRequestDetailsModel> y = x.details;
```

If you want to access a specific item in that list then you should loop through them and find the one you want. Or use an index or some other method that gets a specific item.

For example, the first item you could get like so:

```
StoreToStoreRequestDetailsModel first = x.details[0];
```

Though I suggest you validate to ensure there are any items first.

Comment: Thanks that works! But then I cant access the properties of the details by using "y.<intellisense>". I am trying to bind the details to a list view from the object "temp".

Comment: @lrnc_vlsc: That is because you have a `List`... you need to choose which item in that list you want to work with